# MSSQL case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a view which only shows me values which have a % in it.

I tried following

```
 Alter VIEW [dbo].[history] as

    select 

    [objid]
          ,[interval]
          ,[value_channel]
          ,[value_channelid]
          ,case when [value_text] like '[%]' then right([value text],2)
          ,[value_raw_text]
          ,[coverage_raw]

    from .....
```

but I get the error
Incorrect syntax near ','.

any idea?

Comment: Classic. You forgot the "end" at the end of the case.

Answer (score 5):

There are tow things missing in your alter view statement:

One is the `end` after the `case`, and the other one is an alias to the column.

```
Alter VIEW [dbo].[history] as

select 

[objid]
      ,[interval]
      ,[value_channel]
      ,[value_channelid]
      ,case when [value_text] like '[%]' then right([value_text],2) end as value_text
      ,[value_raw_text]
      ,[coverage_raw]

from .....
```

You might also want to add an `else` to the `case` expression, otherwise it will simply return `null` when the condition is not matched:

```
Alter VIEW [dbo].[history] as

select 

[objid]
      ,[interval]
      ,[value_channel]
      ,[value_channelid]
      ,case when [value_text] like '[%]' then right([value_text],2) else [value_text] end as value_text
      ,[value_raw_text]
      ,[coverage_raw]

from .....
```